# Reference request: proof that the first hitting time of a Borel set is a stopping time

Tags: measure-theory, reference-request, stochastic-processes, stopping-times

Where exactly (book and page number) can I find the proof that the first hitting time of a Borel set a "Stopping time" (continuous time). My notes say it is a deep theorem, particularly hard to prove but didn't give any reference. 
Moreover my prof mentioned that is is so hard to prove that the famous mathematician Laurent Schwarz suggested that one should use this definition of a stopping time/hitting time

Comment: Is the stochastic process you're thinking of progressively measurable?

Comment: Schwartz with a "t". The quote is dubious, any source for it?

Comment: @Did It was stated verbatim by my Prof Francois Coquet so yes it's probably dubious and I don't have any reference :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result is known as a Début theorem. Many proofs in the literature use capacities to prove the measurability of the hitting time $$\tau_B := \inf\{t \geq 0; X_t \in B\}$$ (see e.g. Dellacherie & Meyer), but there is also a proof by Bass which is rather elementary. Note that the result is much easier to prove for some particular cases:

1. $(X_t)_t$ is right-continuous and $B$ is open.
2. $(\mathcal{F}_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is complete filtration, $(X_t)_{t \geq
   0}$ is a Markov process with càdlàg sample paths and $B$ is closed.

For a proof in the first setting see e.g. Schilling & Partzsch, a proof
for the second one you can find in Itô's book (see also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1514488/36150)).

- R.F. Bass: The measurability of hitting times. Electronic
  communications in Probability 15 (2010), 99-105.
- C. Dellacherie, P.-A. Meyer. Probabilities and Potential
- K. Itô: Stochastic Processes
- R.L. Schilling & L. Partzsch: Brownian Motion

Comment: @user3503589 You are welcome.

Comment: https://www.google.de/amp/s/almostsure.wordpress.com/2009/11/15/stopping-times-and-the-debut-theorem/amp/?client=safari . Isn't this the first entry into a closed set ?

Comment: @user3503589 Yeah, sure... it is a particular case of the general statement.

Comment: so I should check the book . Thanks a to. . You are always there to answer my questions . I really appreciate it .

Comment: @user3503589 See also this question/answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1514488/