# Hitting time into closed sets for strong markov Processes $(X_t)_{t\geq 0}$ (Peskir & Shiryaev)

Tags: probability-theory, stopping-times

I was reading the book Optimal Stopping and Free Boundary Problems by Peskir & Shiryaev and came across an interesting statement. The setting is as follows.

> Let $(X_t)_{t\geq0}$  with state space $E=\mathbb{R}^d$ equipped with
>   the $\sigma$-field $\mathcal{B} = \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^d)$, be a
>   strong Markov Process with right-continuous paths defined on the
>   canonical pathspace space $(E^{[0,\infty)},\mathcal{B}^{[0,\infty)},
> > P_x)$. Furthermore let $(\mathcal{F}_t)_{t\geq 0}$ be a
>   right-continuous filtration and let $X_t$ be measurable w.r.t
>   $\mathcal{F}_t$  for all $t\geq 0$. Let $G: E \to \mathbb{R}$ be
>   measurable and upper-semi-continuous and $V(x) = \sup_{\tau} \mathbb{E}_x(G(X_{\tau}))$ (where $\tau  $ is an almost surely finite
>   stopping time) be lower-semi-continuous. Consider the closed set $D =  \{x\in E \mid V(x) = G(x) \}$.

The author states that $\tau_{D} = \inf\{t\geq 0 \mid X_t \in D \}$ is a stopping time w.r.t. $(\mathcal{F}_t)_{t\geq 0 }$, since $(X_t)_{t\geq 0}$ has right-continuous paths and $(\mathcal{F}_t)_{t\geq 0}$ is right-continuous.

My question is why is that so ? I know that $\tau_{D}$ is a stopping time if, D is open or $X$ has continuous paths or $\mathcal{F_0}$ is $P_x$-complete for all $x\in E$. I would appreciate either reference or a solution for this statement.

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1719988/36150)

Comment: I am afraid the answers presented cannot be used in my cause, because the reference presented, are for RCLL processes and secondly those proofs rely on completeness of the Filtration, which is not the case here.