# Stopping times of càdlàg processes

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis, stopping-times

Assuming the usual conditions hold and that X ist càdlàg, how can we proof, that for a closed subset $A\subset \mathbb{R}$ the random variable

$\tau := \inf\{ t\geq 0: X_t\in A \mbox{ or} X_{t-}\in A\}$

is a stopping time?

Edit, a little bit more explanation:

So because $A$ is closed, we get
        $$X_t(\omega )\in A \Leftrightarrow \text{dist}(X_t(\omega),A)=0.$$
        And for the left limes $X_{t-}$ we get
        $$X_{t-}(\omega )\in A \Leftrightarrow \lim\limits_{ t_n \uparrow t, t_n\not=t } \text{dist}(X_{t_n}(\omega), A)=0$$
because $X$ is càdlàg.
        So it is correct to write (and because the usual conditions hold we only need to look at $\{ \tau < t\}$)
        $$\{ \tau < t\} = \{ \inf\limits_{ u\in [0,t) } \text{dist}(X_u, A) = 0\}.$$
        And we can rewrite this:
         $$   \left\{ \inf\limits_{ u\in [0,t) } \text{dist}(X_u, A) 
= 0\right\}
= \bigcap_{n\in \mathbb{N}}  \left\{   \inf\limits_{ u\in [0,t) } \text{dist}(X_u, A) < 1/n \right\} \\=\bigcap_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \left\{ \bigcup_{ u \in \mathbb{Q} \cap [0,t) } \left\{ \text{dist}(X_u, A) < 1/n \right\}  \right\}.$$
        And because of $\left\{ \text{dist}(X_u, A) < 1/n \right\}  \in \mathcal{F}_u \subset\mathcal{F}_t$ we get
        $$\bigcap_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \left\{ \bigcup_{ u \in \mathbb{Q} \cap [0,t) } \left\{ \text{dist}(X_u, A) < 1/n \right\}  \right\} \in \mathcal{F}_t,$$
    So $\left\{ \tau < t \right\}\in \mathcal{F}_t$. So $\tau$ is a stopping time.

Comment: Your stopping time $\tau_i$ does actually not depend on $i$, which makes it somewhat unclear what you are trying to do. (Moreover, you would need to show that $\inf\{t \geq 0; X_t \in A\}$ is a stopping time...this is not trivial. See this [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1514488/36150) (...and the answer to it.))

Comment: Thx! It should be: $ \tau_i=\inf\{ t> \tau_{i-1}: X_{t}\not=X_{t-}\}, i\geq 1$. I want to show, that $T_C$ of the first answer in the question you linked is a stopping time...

Comment: Did you read my comment (and/or the other answer)? To make your approach, you would need to show that $\inf\{t; X_t \in A\}$ is a stopping time... which is much more difficult than showing that $\tau$ (defined in your question) is a stopping time. In the answer, which I linked, you can find an approach how to prove that $\tau$ is a stopping time.

Comment: Oh... I got it now, sorry... But I don’t see a proof for my problem there?

Comment: So, I think it's somehow much easier than I thought? $\{ \tau \leq t\} = \{ \inf\limits_{ u\in [0,t] } \text{dist}(X_u, A) = 0\} = \bigcap_{n\in  \mathbb{N}} \{ \inf\limits_{ u\in [0,t] } \text{dist}(X_u, A) < 1/n \} = \bigcap_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \left\{ \bigcup_{ u\in \mathbb{Q}\cap [0,t] }\{ \text{dist}(X_u, A) < 1/n \} \right\}$.

Comment: And $ \{ \text{dist}(X_u, A) < 1/n \} \in \mathcal{F}_u \subseteq \mathcal{F}_t$?


The first equality above is because $A$ is closed, the second one because $X$ is càdlàg. Is that right?

Comment: Could you please edit the body of your question instead of writing it as a comment? It is then much easier to read and, additionally, future readers of your question won't have to read through all the comments

Comment: Ahhh, sorry... I did that!

Comment: Looks okay (...though càdlàg is needed for the first identity and not for the second, I think).

Comment: Thx! So if $A$ is open, the first equality is of course not true. ( $\text{dist}(0, (0,1) )=0$ but $0\not\in (0,1)$. But the definition of $\inf_{u\in [0,t] \text{dist}(X_u, A)$ doesn't make any sense if $X$ isn't càdlàg! 

So we need, that $A$ is closed and that $X$ is càdlàg. And the second and third equality do not need that... 

Thank you! :-)

Comment: Sorry... 

So if $A$ is open, the first equality is of course not true. ( $\text{dist}(0, (0,1) )=0$ but $0\not\in (0,1)$. But the definition of $\inf_{u\in [0,t]} \text{dist}(X_u, A)$ doesn't make any sense if $X$ isn't càdlàg! 

So we need, that $A$ is closed and that $X$ is càdlàg. And the second and third equality do not need that... 

I added that in my main post!


I have one remaining question: Where did I use, that the filtration is right continous?

Comment: So for $t\in \mathbb{R}\backslash\mathbb{Q}$ I changed $\bigcup_{ u \in \mathbb{Q} \cap [0,t]}$ to $\bigcup_{ u \in \mathbb{Q} \cap [0,t] \cup \{t\}}$.

Comment: I corrected a few little faults and played around with this stopping time a little bit in another question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3404444/implication-of-a-positive-endvalue-of-a-martingale-m-t-t-in-0-t