# Implication of a positive endvalue of a martingale $(M_t)_{t\in [0,T]}$

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales, stochastic-analysis, stopping-times

Playing around with two frequently asked questions ([Stopping times of càdlàg processes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399633/stopping-times-of-c%c3%a0dl%c3%a0g-processes?noredirect=1#comment6997278_3399633), [Stopping times and the left limit](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3402854/stopping-times-and-the-left-limit/3402907?noredirect=1#comment7002014_3402907)) I got curious if the concept of preservable stopping times (see the first answer to the second question) couldn't be used for a simple proof of the following implication:

$$(M_t)_{t\in [0,T|} \mbox{ càdlàg }, P(M_T>0=1) \Rightarrow P( \inf\limits_{t\in [0,T]} M_t>0)=1$$

So define $\tau$ as in the first question for $A:=[-\infty, 0]$, so
$$\tau := \inf\{ t\geq 0: X_t\in A \mbox{ or } X_{t-}\in A\}.$$

Define for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ the stopping times:
$$\tau_n := \inf \left\{ t\geq0: M_t < 1/n \right\}.$$

It is obvious, that $\tau_n\leq \tau$ a.s. But does the fact $\tau_n<\tau$ also hold almust surely on $\{\tau<T\}$? (I think it is not needed on $\{\tau =T\}$, because we know, that $M$ does not jump to 0 at $T$.) One could imagine, that $M$ stays above $1/n>x>2/n$ for a time and then jumps from $x$ to $0$ and so we would have $\tau_1<\tau_2=\tau$. In this case, the Theorem stated in the second question would not be useful. But I think, we can proof that $\tau_n<\tau$ holds on $\{ 0< \tau <T\}$ ( even on $\{ \tau <T\}$, because of $E[M_T]=E[M_0]$ we can not have $M_0\leq 0$, as it would be a contradiction to $P(M_T>0)=1$).

So let's assume, that $\{\tau_n=\tau<T\}$ has positive probability.That means $ P(\{M_{\tau_n} \leq 0\})>0$. Because of 
$$E[M_T| M_{\tau_n} ]= M_{\tau_n}$$
we get $P( M_T \leq 0)>0$, right?  That would be a contradiction.

So we really have $\tau_n<\tau$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and could apply the Theorem stated in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3402907/615367 ?

But I think this proof could be shortend without this concept: 
So assuming $P( \inf\limits_{t\in [0,T]} M_t\leq 0)>0$ and $P( M_T>0)=1$ we get
$$P( \inf\limits_{t\in [0,T)} M_t\leq 0)>0$$
and so
$$P\left( \inf\left\{ t\geq 0: M_t \in A \mbox{ oder }M_{t-}\in A \right\} <T\right)=P( \tau <T ) >0$$

Because of
$$ E\left[ M_T | M_{\tau_n } \right]= M_{\tau_n }$$
and $\{ \tau_n < T  \} \subset \{ M_{\tau_n } \leq 0  \}$ we immediately get $P\left( M_t \leq 0 \right)>0$ which is again a contradiction?

So am I assuming something terribly wrong here or did I play around with these concepts correctly? I am not quite sure at the moment, that there isn't something wrong.

Comment: I'll need to think a bit more about the approach you take, but I now remember that there is a fairly simple proof of the implication you want. It is implied by Theorem 5.4.4 in Cohen and Elliott. The basic approach seems reminiscent of yours, so perhaps you do have the right idea.

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist I will also have a look at this Theorem!

Comment: I think, the last step is wrong. I should do it that way: $P( \tau <T)\geq \varepsilon$ gives us $P( \forall n: E[M_T| M_{\tau_n}] \leq 1/n])= P( \forall n: \tau_n<T)\geq \varepsilon$ and that gives us $P(M_T\leq 0)>0$? But for that we do not need the result, that on $\{ \tau <T\}$ we can not jump to zero?

Comment: Btw — I’ve been quite busy lately so I haven’t had the chance to think about this properly. Just letting you know that I haven’t forgotten about your question, and I’ll get to it when I find the time.

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist That's very nice of you! Thx :-)